# Azure development Environment

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Other than Credit Card required 3 month trial period are there any other approach to experience Azure development.
Something like Visual Studio installed SDK?
My gut tells me there has to be, but I can't find anything.

Comment: A question modification,Answer,explanation would have been nice for me and the community other than a down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Azure Emulator on your local dev environment.  It comes with the Azure SDK.

The current version of the SDK 2.5.  You can read about it: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/12/announcing-azure-sdk-2-5-for-net-and-visual-studio-2015-preview/

and download it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44938

Answer (score 1):

Most of the azure can be experienced on a dev environment. It depends on which service you would like to use. You can do a search on azure documentation and you should be able to figure it out. For example, this is how you can use [Azure Storage in a dev environment](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/).